# Как динамически изменять значение ключа в объекте?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть файл dynamic-configs.js

```
let currentConfig = 'second';
const changeConfig = (config) => {
    currentConfig = config;
}

const dynamicConfigValue = (key) => {
    return `${currentConfig}:${key}`;
}

module.exports = {
    changeConfig,
    dynamicConfigValue,
}
```

И файл solution.js

```
module.exports = function(configValue) {
        // решение должно быть в этой функции
  const makeDynamicConfig = e => e;
  const dynamicConfigValue = configValue;

  return {
    makeDynamicConfig,
    dynamicConfigValue,
  };
}
```

И файл в котором я изменяю значение ключа

```
const fs = require('fs');

const example = require('./src/example');
const solution = require(`./src/solution`);

const { changeConfig, dynamicConfigValue } = require('./src/dynamic-configs');

const newFns = solution(dynamicConfigValue);

const result = example(newFns, changeConfig);

changeConfig('4');  // Ожидается ответ 4:key1, но в переменной как и осталось значение second, такой и ответ second:key1

console.log(result.objectFirst.key)

fs.writeFileSync('./output.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Как менять переменную currentKey, используя changeConfig() и решение самое в файле solution.js.
Если есть статьи о динамической конфигурации или о чем-то, что может приблизить меня к ответу скиньте пожалуйста, буду рада помощи!

Comment: А где в вашем примере переменная currentKey?